# "ValueError: attributes needs to be a callable, a list or a dict" on mezzanine admin

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

im using Django + Mezzanine and getting and unknow problem.
When i try to create a new page, blogpost or anything in the mezzanine admin interface i receive the folowing message: "ValueError: attributes needs to be a callable, a list or a dict".

This error ocures only on production on my server, at the local testing runs ok.

Im using Mezzanine 4.1.0 and Django 1.9 on both servers

[Print of the error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwEGq.png)

Comment: Looks like the exception is being raised in the bleach library. I'm guessing this is one of the common bleach/html5lib version incompatibility issues folks have been seeing a lot lately. You might search the mailing list for resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Ryne's correct.  Perhaps the easiest way to make it go again is:

```
pip install 'bleach<2.0'
```

which fixed it for me.  A [bug has been reported](https://bitbucket.org/akhayyat/mezzanine-pagedown/issues/25/bleach-20-insists-on-a-list-not-a-tuple) against bleach, but the fix only came 2018-4-4, so it might not be propagated yet.